# How to configure dired to update instantly when files/folders change?

Tags: filesystems, emacs, dired

Sometimes I launch dired, then rename a file, or add a new file, and dired doesn't see the changes until I relaunch Emacs. Is there a way to configure dired to refresh itself more quickly, either through polling or file system hooks?

Comment: Use `revert-buffer`. Default binding `g`.

Comment: @KAction Upvote. Very useful, but not automatic.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Add a [hook](https://github.com/mcandre/dotfiles/blob/master/emacs#L131).

```
;; Auto-refresh dired on file change
(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook 'auto-revert-mode)
```

Comment: Thanks man, it works like charm.

Answer (score 0):

`(setq dired-do-revert-buffer t)`

Automatically revert Dired buffers after ‘dired-do’ operations.
This option controls whether to refresh the directory listing in a
Dired buffer that is the destination of one of these operations:
‘dired-do-copy’, ‘dired-do-rename’, ‘dired-do-symlink’, ‘dired-do-hardlink’.
If the value is t, always revert the Dired buffer updated in the result
of these operations.
If the value is a function, it is called with the destination directory name
as a single argument, and the buffer is reverted after Dired operations
if the function returns non-nil.

This variable was introduced in version 28.1 of Emacs.